# jquery not displaying data in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to create a cart system, where I want to display data according to member number. I am getting data from controller perfectly, but it's not displaying in HTML. I am sharing the console result here :

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var get_price_per_head;
      var members;

      $('.increment').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var quantity = $(this).parent('div').find('.qua').html();
        var package_type_id = $(this).parent('div').find('.package_type_id').val();
        var increased_val = parseInt(quantity) + 1;
        console.log(package_type_id);
        $(this).parent('div').find('.qua').html(increased_val);

        $.ajax({
          url: 'get_package_type_price',
          method: 'GET',
          data: {
            package_type_id: package_type_id,
            member_number: increased_val
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            get_price_per_head = data.get_price_per_head;
            console.log(get_price_per_head);
            $(this).parent("div").find(".price_per_head").html(get_price_per_head);
          }
        });
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-grp">
  <p>Total Members</p>
  <div class="btn-grp" data-id="{{ $id }}">
    <button class="btn-outline-dark update-cart-button 
                                        decrement" id="decrement">-</button>
    <strong><span class="qua" id="quantity"> 
                                         {{$details['number_of_members']}}</span></strong>
    <button class="btn-outline-dark update-cart-button 
                                         increment" id="increment">+</button>
    <input type="hidden" class="package_type_id" value=" 
                                    {{$details['package_type_id']}}">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item-grp" data-id="{{ $id }}">
  <p>Cost Per-member</p>
  <strong>$<span class="price_per_head">{{ 
                                    $details['price_per_head'] }}</span></strong>
</div>
```

screenshot for console of `$(this).parent("div").find(".price_per_head")`

[image]

Comment: Please post RENDERED HTML. I made you a snippet. Please edit it into a [mcve] - you are for example missing the last `})`

Comment: It seems a little pointless to me to first put `{{ $details['price_per_head'] }}` into `.price_per_head` just to replace it with the result of the ajax call as soon as it is resolved.

Comment: Can you add `$(this).parent("div").find(".price_per_head")` to your `console.log(get_price_per_head);`?

Comment: @shaedrich I have updated the question with the console, please check at the bottom

Comment: That indicates, that your element couldn't be found by jQuery.

Comment: I use to reverse engineer it this way: `console.log(this, $(this).parent("div"), $(this).parent("div").find(".price_per_head"))`

Comment: Maybe, the `this` scope was changed by AJAX ...

Comment: @shaedrich It (this) works for other elements, for example, when incrementing/decrementing. I guess the parent("div") does not getting the right parent

Answer (score 0):

AJAX changes the [`this` scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) so you can do this instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var get_price_per_head;
      var members;

      $('.increment').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var quantity = $(this).parent('div').find('.qua').html();
        var package_type_id = $(this).parent('div').find('.package_type_id').val();
        var increased_val = parseInt(quantity) + 1;
        console.log(package_type_id);
        $(this).parent('div').find('.qua').html(increased_val);

        $.ajax({
          url: 'get_package_type_price',
          method: 'GET',
          data: {
            package_type_id: package_type_id,
            member_number: increased_val
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            get_price_per_head = data.get_price_per_head;
            console.log(get_price_per_head);
            $(e.target).parent("div").find(".price_per_head").html(get_price_per_head);
          }
        });
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-grp">
  <p>Total Members</p>
  <div class="btn-grp" data-id="{{ $id }}">
    <button class="btn-outline-dark update-cart-button 
                                        decrement" id="decrement">-</button>
    <strong><span class="qua" id="quantity"> 
                                         {{$details['number_of_members']}}</span></strong>
    <button class="btn-outline-dark update-cart-button 
                                         increment" id="increment">+</button>
    <input type="hidden" class="package_type_id" value=" 
                                    {{$details['package_type_id']}}">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item-grp" data-id="{{ $id }}">
  <p>Cost Per-member</p>
  <strong>$<span class="price_per_head">{{ 
                                    $details['price_per_head'] }}</span></strong>
</div>
```

If you like to keep using `this`:

```js
function onSuccess(data) {
    get_price_per_head = data.get_price_per_head;
    console.log(get_price_per_head);
    $(this).parent("div").find(".price_per_head").html(get_price_per_head);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
      var get_price_per_head;
      var members;

      $('.increment').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var quantity = $(this).parent('div').find('.qua').html();
        var package_type_id = $(this).parent('div').find('.package_type_id').val();
        var increased_val = parseInt(quantity) + 1;
        console.log(package_type_id);
        $(this).parent('div').find('.qua').html(increased_val);

        $.ajax({
          url: 'get_package_type_price',
          method: 'GET',
          data: {
            package_type_id: package_type_id,
            member_number: increased_val
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: onSuccess.bind(this)
        });
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-grp">
  <p>Total Members</p>
  <div class="btn-grp" data-id="{{ $id }}">
    <button class="btn-outline-dark update-cart-button 
                                        decrement" id="decrement">-</button>
    <strong><span class="qua" id="quantity"> 
                                         {{$details['number_of_members']}}</span></strong>
    <button class="btn-outline-dark update-cart-button 
                                         increment" id="increment">+</button>
    <input type="hidden" class="package_type_id" value=" 
                                    {{$details['package_type_id']}}">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item-grp" data-id="{{ $id }}">
  <p>Cost Per-member</p>
  <strong>$<span class="price_per_head">{{ 
                                    $details['price_per_head'] }}</span></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: It (this) works for other elements, for example, when incrementing/decrementing. I guess the parent("div") does not getting the right parent

Comment: Yes, it can't find the parent since `this` is pointing to the AJAX object instead of the jQuery element object bound to the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first empty the div then append:

```
$('.price_per_head').empty();

$('.price_per_head').append(get_price_per_head);
```

This will empty the content inside a span with class `price_per_head` then append your value of `get_price_per_head`

If its inside loop then, try to give a unique class name for every loop.

Comment: It (this) works for other elements, for example, when incrementing/decrementing. I guess the parent("div") does not getting the right parent